# Has Iran (or proxies) proposed any long-term strategies for the destruction of Israel?

Tags: israel, iran

The general consensus is that Iran and its proxies (e.g., Hamas and Hezbollah) long for the destruction of the Jewish state, viewing it as an usurping colonial entity in Arab Muslim lands. Let us assume that this view is correct. Given that Iran does long for the destruction of Israel and views it as a legitimate (if lofty) geopolitical objective, what strategies does it have to accomplish this?

Many, especially those on the pro-Israel side, argue that the core of the strategy is the Iranian nuclear program. Per this view, Iran wishes to develop nuclear weapons and once it has nuclear weapons will plunge the world into nuclear armageddon to accomplish its goal of destroying Israel. One argument used to bolster this position is that the Iranian mullahs, being religious fanatics, are not deterred by the usual MAD rationale against the usage of nuclear weapons.

This view seems naive and polemical. There's no reason to think that the Iranians are suicidal or lack the self-preservation instincts that all states do. Furthermore, their conduct in the recent war in the Middle East indicates that they are surprisingly rational and circumspect by e.g., refusing to escalate despite Israeli provocations like the assassination of al-Arouri and Razi Mousavi.

I wonder if Iran has a more serious "long game" to destroy Israel.

> Has Iran proposed any (non-nuclear) long-term strategy for the destruction of Israel?

One hypothesis may be that Iran uses militant groups like Hamas and Hezbollah to destabilize and demotivate Israel, prodding it to launch brutal wars which incur international condemnation (e.g., at the ICJ) as happened recently. In the long-term this could make Israel a pariah. However, this is just a guess and I have no evidence to substantiate it.

Comment: Right now this question seems biased to many. I think removing the section about whether on not Iran’s use of nukes is possible/reasonable will fix this, but since I don’t know much about the topic I can’t say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

IDK if they've ever even been incredibly specific, and/or if you can take their rhetoric super seriously, but e.g. [in 2022](https://www.iranintl.com/en/202208065484):

> Ghaani repeated a recent refrain heard from other Iranian officials that Israel is in decline and said that “Hezbollah’s sons are making plans to bring down the last blow against the Zionist regime … and to realize the wish of Imam Khomeini to eradicate Israel from the map and the face of the Earth.”

So, yeah, ["for great justice"] they seem to prefer that a Shia militia does that, rather than e.g. some Palestinian group. Or maybe I'm not sufficiently familiar with their jargon and "Hezbollah’s sons" refers to some broader group[s]--but anyhow, it's interesting nonetheless that they mention them.